# WebRTC adding remote streams using pc.ontrack not working

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I am trying to setup a webrtc peerconnection, but on receiving remote tracks no video or audio is playing in the html video element.

I think the issue is with multipal tracks that I am receiving, a total of 4 with 2 video and 2 audio tracks, **Images Attached**.

**Note**:- Offer, Answer and ICE candidate setup is working fine!

```
RemoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = new MediaStream();

peerconnection.ontrack = (event) => {
   event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
   RemoteVideoRef.current.srcObject.addTrack(track);
  });
};
```

[image: first-2/4 tacks revived]

[image: next-2/4 tracks received]

Answer (score 1):

I have a Solution for this Look at this Code...

HTML CODE: You need only the Video tag.

Index.html

```
<video id="remoteScreen"  autoplay="true"></video>
```

Screenshare.js file

```
const getLocalScreenCaptureStream = async () => {try {
const constraints = { video: { cursor: 'always' }, audio: false };
const screenCaptureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints); 
return screenCaptureStream
} catch (error) {
console.error('failed to get local screen', error)
}
}
```

main.js

```
var localStreamScreen = null;
async function shareScreen() {localStreamScreen = await getLocalScreenCaptureStream(); console.log("localStreamScreen: ", localStreamScreen)}
```

screenshare.js

```
function handleRemoteStreamAddedScreen(event) {
console.log('Remote stream added.');
alert('Remote stream added.');
 if ('srcObject' in remoteScreen) {
remoteScreen.srcObject = event.streams[0];
 } else {
// deprecated
remoteScreen.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
}
 remoteScreenStream = event.stream};
```

I Hope, it will work for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope, I don't think so this relates to my question, the issue is with WebRTC peer connection ontarck() method.

Comment: Can you please give me full code for solve and issue. And btw this code is of Webrtc screen sharing project. I have code for screen sharing, Mouse move from client side and also feature of Keyboards.

Comment: I have a similar issue. In my case, it was caused by ICE Candidate mismatch. If you have a user.name in SDP, ensure the user.name is the same in ICE candidate that you are sending.